# GridBagLayouts in GridLayout

Tags: swing, user-interface, layout-manager, grid-layout, gridbaglayout

Trying to build about this GUI in Swing:

[image]

In my MainFrame i set a GridLayout like that to achieve 1 row, 2 columns:

```
setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
```

In the Left Column i figures i would need a GridBagLayout as in the right column. Normal GridLayout doesn't work anymore because i want different sizes of each row. For the left column i tried this:

```
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    mapPanel = new MapPanel(map);
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridheight = 10;
    add(mapPanel, gbc);

    controlPanel = new JPanel();
    controlPanel.add(new JButton("Test"));
    controlPanel.add(new JButton("Test 2"));
    controlPanel.add(new JButton("Test 3"));
    controlPanel.add(new JButton("Test 4"));
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    add(controlPanel, gbc);

    logPanel = new LogPanel();
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    gbc.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    add(logPanel, gbc);
```

This however will result in everything "packed together" in the left column. It won't expand to the 100% height and 50% width the column has. How can i achieve a GUI as in the picture?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you experiment with `setPreferredSize(Dimension)` of the components that you layout? This property is closely related to how layout managers present the result.

Comment: @HummelingEngineering  See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I agree it's better not to tweak a component's preferred size, but layout managers tend to use them, even when not set by 'us'. My comment was pointing in that direction... hope my answer is a little better.

Comment: *"I agree it's better not to tweak a component's preferred size,"*  The advice in that thread does not say not to 'tweak' them, just not to call **set.**  If necessary, **override** the default method, but it is **not** necessary here.  An empty border can pad a label, and a text field has the `setColumns(int)` method to suggest a size.  **Trying to guess the required size of a component will result in a fragile GUI.**

Comment: @AndrewThompson with "tweak" I actually meant "set", which might have been better in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [JNodeLayout](https://github.com/andronix3/jnodelayout). RectNode is exactly what you Need.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

import com.smartg.swing.layout.JNodeLayout;
import com.smartg.swing.layout.LayoutNode.RectNode;

public class RectNodeDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String rootName = "root";
        RectNode root = new RectNode(rootName);
        JNodeLayout layout = new JNodeLayout(root);
        layout.setHgap(1);
        layout.setVgap(1);


        JPanel target = new JPanel();
        target.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

        target.setLayout(layout);

        addPanel(target, root, new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, .5, .5));
        addPanel(target, root, new Rectangle2D.Double(0, .5, .5, .1));
        addPanel(target, root, new Rectangle2D.Double(0, .6, .5, .4));  

        addPanel(target, root, new Rectangle2D.Double(.5, 0, .5, .9));
        addPanel(target, root, new Rectangle2D.Double(.5, .9, .5, .1));

        layout.syncNodes();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPane.add(target, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static void addPanel(JPanel target, RectNode node, Rectangle2D r) {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        target.add(p);
        p.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
        node.add(p, r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Relative Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/). This layout allows you to specify the relative sizes of each component.

To create your panel on the left the code would be something like:

```
RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(RelativeLayout.Y_AXIS);
rl.setFill( true );
JPanel left = new JPanel( rl );
left.add(panel1, new Float(50));
left.add(panel2, new Float(10));
left.add(panel3, new Float(40));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only `GridBagLayout` will suffice.

By setting `gbc.gridheight = 10` you tell GridBag to use 10 rows for the component. (Similar to `rowspan` in HTML.) This, however, says nothing about the actual height of the component since rows don't have a fixed height. Consequently, this constraint doesn't have any effect when you're only using a single column. The name of the constraint is IMHO confusing.

Use `GridBagConstraints.weightx` and `GridBagConstraints.weighty` to specify where extra space should go. See [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more.

In combination with component's preferred sizes you'll be able to obtain a panel that will show your components when the panel is small and distribute extra space when the panel is 'too big'.

Though, as Andrew Thompson pointed out, using `setPreferredSize()` is not a very good way to go. Often, components already have their preferred size just fine as constructed. Just play around with all of `GridBagConstraints` and see what happens.

This might in the end be a better looking solution.